# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] keeps occuring for a program even tho same method works for another program

Tags: python, filepath

I tried this method to make a new directory and add files to it.The new folder is made when i check the directory but the output i get is FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Kean\Desktop\test\automateprojects\tos\'

```
os.makedirs(r"C:\Users\Kean\Desktop\test\automateprojects\tos",exist_ok=True)
url="https://imgur.com/search/score/all?q_type=png&q_all=football"
res = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
temp = soup.select('a[class="image-list-link"]')
temp1=temp[0].select('img')
t=temp1[0].get('src')
newurl="http:"+t
print(newurl)
pes=requests.get(newurl)
playFile=open(os.path.join(r"C:\Users\Kean\Desktop\test\automateprojects\tos",
os.path.basename(t)),'wb')
playFile.write(pes.content)
playFile.close()
```

I used the exact same method in another program which exists in the same directory and it works perfectly fine,only difference being I change the new directory name from tos to xkcd. The program makes a new folder called tos but then I get the error that the directory doesnt exist.

Comment: Is that error being thrown on the `playFile=open(...` line? Is it possible that the directory name wasn't updated on both lines?

Comment: @nighthawk454 Yes the error is for the playFile=open(...  line . What do u mean that the directory name isnt updated for both lines?

Comment: You mentioned you changed the directory name from 'tos' to 'xkcd'. Perhaps there's some weird file path stuff going on with Windows paths and r strings. You could try `pathlib` in the standard library – should be a bit simpler. Fwiw this works on my machine, though I'm on Mac so the paths are different.

Comment: @nighthawk454 thanks a ton man. The problem was that the t variable was not loading as a string thus making it search for a file that did exist in the directory. Just had to convert it into a string and all is good. Thanks for the suggestions about pathlib, im gonna start using that from now on :P